# how to add ssh key to host via bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, ssh-keys

I've been trying to automate the creation of a user and configuration of the ssh access.

So far I created a script that access the host and creates the new user via expect, as follows:

```
expect -c '
spawn ssh '$user'@'$ip';
expect "assword: ";
send "'$passwd'\r";
expect "prompt\n";
send "adduser '$new_user'\r";
...
send "mkdir /home/'$new_user'/.ssh\r";
expect "prompt\n";
send "exit\r";
'
```

This works fine, after that I need to add the .pub key file to the authorized keys file in the host, there is where hell started.

I tried:

```
ssh_key='/home/.../key.pub'
content=$(cat $ssh_key)
expect -c '
spawn ssh '$user'@'$ip' "echo '$content' >> /home/'$new_user'/.ssh/authorized_keys;
expect "password:";
...
'
```

and got:

```
missing "
    while executing 
"spawn ssh root@000.00.00.00 ""
couldn't read file "<ssh .pub key content> ...
```

I tried also:

```
cat $ssh_key | ssh $user@$ip "cat >> /home/$new_user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Without success, I only get the password query blinking, I can't connect the expect with this last method.

Comment: You might make a habit of using http://shellcheck.net/ -- it would have caught your bug.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to ignore the larger problems here and focus specifically on your question. (There *are* larger problems: Don't use `expect` here -- if you rely on `sshpass` instead you can simplify this script immensely).

Right now, when you close your single quotes, you aren't starting any other kind of quotes. That means that when you substitute a variable with whitespace, you end the `-c` argument passed to `expect`.

Instead of doing this:

```
'foo'$bar'baz'
```

do this:

```
'foo'"$bar"'baz'
```

...so your script will look more like:

```
ssh_key='/home/.../key.pub'
content=$(<"$ssh_key")
expect -c '
spawn ssh '"$user"'@'"$ip"' "echo '"$content"' >> /home/'"$new_user"'/.ssh/authorized_keys;
expect "password:";
...
'
```

---

In terms of avoiding this altogether, though, consider something more like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh

content=$(<"$ssh_key") # more efficient alternative to $(cat ...)

# generate shell-quoted versions of your variables
# these are safe to substitute into a script
# ...even if the original content contains evil things like $(rm -rf /*)
printf -v content_q '%q' "$content"
printf -v new_user_q '%q' "$new_user"

# use those shell-quoted versions remotely
sshpass -f"$password_file" ssh "$host" bash -s <<EOF
adduser ${new_user_q}
printf '%s\n' ${content_q} >>/home/${new_user_q}/.ssh/authorized_keys
EOF
```